# How to implement animated scrolling in YUI3?

Tags: javascript, yui3

I fail to create animated scroll using YUI3.

It should be compatible with iOS inertial scrolling, and I want to trigger animated scrolling programatically. But I can't find correct syntax for YUI3 due to lack of docs.

1) The following code works:

```
   scrollArea._node.scrollLeft = 200; //the element is scrolled!
   // so the variable is defined correctly and CSS also works!
```

2) The following code also works (if I am using absolute positioning to emulate scroll):

```
        animation = new Y.Anim({
            node: content,
            to: {
                left: -200
            }
        });
        animation.run();
```

3) But te following does not:

```
        animation = new Y.Anim({
            node: scrollArea,
            scroll: {
                to: {
                    scrollLeft: 200
                }
            }
        });
        animation.run();
```

4) Here's how the markup looks like:

```
<div class="scroll-area"> <!-- scrollArea, overflow: scroll -->
    <ul class="content"> <!-- content -->
        <li></li><li></li><li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I hope this is merely a question of syntax.
[Here the question is solved for YUI2](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/animation/scroll.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the third example, the issue appears to be your usage of `scroll` as an attribute for the Anim constructor, which is valid for how YUI2's Scroll utility works, but [YUI3's Anim](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/anim/) is much more powerful than that.

You were close with the second attempt. Here is the code revised:

```
    animation = new Y.Anim({
        node: scrollArea,
        to: {
            scrollLeft: 200
        }
    });
    animation.run();
```

I have moved the `scrollLeft` field into the [to attribute](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Anim.html#attr_to) and changed the node to `scrollArea` instead of `content`. If you plan to perform this animated scrolling operation often, then might I suggest creating a wrapper function which reuses a single Anim object. This [example](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/anim/anim-xy.html) may be of use to you in demonstrating such reuse.
Good luck.